# Skip select item when it does not exist sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three types of data source. They share similar structure but with some differences. For example, type A contain a column called grade, but type C does not. When do a sql selection, I want to only write one query (because there are a lot of items to select and majority are the same). That means for type C data source, there will be no grade. Under such circumstance, how do I skip this particular selection.

Illustration of my query is as follows:

```
SELECT
ID,
SUM(Addable) AS addable_sum,
MAX(Date) AS max_date,
GROUP_CONCAT(Char, '_') AS Char
AVG(grade) AS grade --------------> this is what I want to skip when dealing with type C data since there is not such thing in it
FROM TypeCTable ---------------> such table does not have grade column
GROUP BY ID
```

Comment: You are trying to shift your application logic into a query. When your table doesn't have a certain column, then you write another query. Simple as that.

Comment: Use Union and select `0.0 as grade` instead of `AVG()` when selecting from C?

Comment: @fancyPants I know what you said. There are 100 items to select, Type A and Type C only differ in 5. So I do not want to have lengthy queries.

Comment: You have a table for every item? Sounds like you seriously need to reconsider your database design.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Could you write a bit more clearly, please? For example, make changes to my example.

Comment: @fancyPants I am given this data. What else can I do then?

Comment: When they refuse to change that (at least in the long term) find a new employer ;)

Answer (score 1):

could be you need  union select  eg:

```
  SELECT
  ID,
  SUM(Addable) AS addable_sum,
  MAX(Date) AS max_date,
  GROUP_CONCAT(Char, '_') AS Char
  AVG(grade) AS grade 
  FROM TypeATable
  GROUP BY ID
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
  ID,
  SUM(Addable) AS addable_sum,
  MAX(Date) AS max_date,
  GROUP_CONCAT(Char, '_') AS Char
  NULL 
  FROM TypeCTable 
  GROUP BY ID
```

or use UNION for distinct result

Comment: I do not think this is what I need. Imagine I have 100 items to select, the length will be simply doubled.

Comment: I can't image  .. what you need  i can just read  your  question then  for avoid misunderstanding you could post a clear data sample  ,and the expected result  ...